# Array index out of range iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Hi guys I have been stuck with the error 'array index out of range'. I am getting JSON data from the internet and converting it into an array. I have been loading comments (Note : I have posted this question as i couldnt find any question related to my problem)

So I have been loading comments in a jsonData. The code i've been using to load comments is this.

```
api.loadComments(shot.commentsUrl, completion: didLoadComments)
```

The code for completion is this.

```
func didLoadComments(comments : [Comment]){
  self.comments = comments
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It is defined in the tableView...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

//This is where the error occurs
let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = comment.user.name
cell.commentLabel.text = comment.body
cell.avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: comment.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))
return cell
```

and the comments variable is defined like this.

```
var comments : [Comment] = Comment
```

The `loadComments` method is returning comments as shown in the log

[The log which shows comments is not nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8paq.png)

The code for loadComments is this.

```
func loadComments(commentsUrl: String, completion: (([Comment]) -> Void)!) {
let urlString = commentsUrl + "?access_token=" + Config.ACCESS_TOKEN

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
   (data, response, error) -> Void in
   if error != nil {
      print(error!.localizedDescription)
   } else {
      var comments = [Comment]()
      do {
         let commentsData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
         for commentData in commentsData {
            let comment = Comment(data: commentData as! NSDictionary)
            comments.append(comment)
         }
      }
      catch {
      }

      let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion(comments)
         }
      }
   }
   task.resume()
}
```

The numberOfRowsInSection looks like this.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
   return 9 + comments.count
}
```

Feel free to ask me for any more code.

Thanks in advance
Aryan

Comment: If it said index out of range, print your `indexPath.row` and check it when the error occurred.

Comment: The easiest way to investigate this is by putting a breakpoint. You can then inspect and verify that `comments` is what you expect it to be...

Comment: where you are calling the loadComments function ?

Comment: Check the value of self.comments in didLoadComments func... does it return anything. I think the problem here is then parsing the data, you need to iterate through the json, create the comment object and then add it to comments add.. then only in cellforrow you will be able to extract it.

Comment: I am calling loadComments in viewDidLoad @emresancaktar

Comment: What is the exception stack trace?

Comment: Hi the self.comments method returns same as the other methods the photo of the log is in the questions and i have also added the comment class is there a problem in loadComments when i parse the data.. @ArunGupta

Comment: It seems you have not parsed the json to comment object. NSJSONSerialization converts the resonse to json. Now you have iterate through json array and parse it into comment object using key value binding.

Comment: i have edited the answer with the exception stack trace @Wain

Comment: Doesnt this line  let comment = comments[indexPath.row] iterate through?? @ArunGupta  Please bear in mind i am fairly new to iOS Development

Comment: @ArunGupta i think i have found it i will have to use a for loop..

Answer (score 0):

The reason of that problem is :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}
```

This method return your items count. And your method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CommentCell


        return cell
    }
```

will run in cycle for each item in this list. 
You should check items count in method **"numberOfRowsInSection"** and items count in **"cellForRowAtIndexPath"**

**EDITED :**

Of course you did.

```
return 9 + comments.count
```

if your comments count will be **0** your fun **cellForRowAtIndexPath** will call **9** times!!!
Use

```
comments.count
```

or add some checks in your code.

Comment: I think there is no need to check the count. If the count is 0 then cellforrow will not even be called. So  cellforrow will be called the numberof count we have.

Comment: i have edited the answer to show numberOfRowsInSection as it returns what i want when i put placeholder text and image..

Comment: After you have add more "numberOfRowsInSection" its very easy to understand whats wrong

Comment: If you dynamically change comments , count is not exception ) if u get 12 comments from server u return 9 + 12 items ? why ??? U will always have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can proceed with it.

Create a Comment class:

```
class Comment {
   var user: User?
   var commentLabel: String?
}
```

Create a User class:

```
class User {
    var name: String?
    var avatarUrl: UIImageView?
}
```

Then in your for loop parse the Json into Comment object and then add it to comments array:

```
for commentData in commentsData {
        let commentDictionary = Comment(data: commentData as! NSDictionary)
            var temp:NSArray = commentDictionary["user"] as! NSArray
            var user: User?
            user.name = temp["name"]
            user.avatarUrl = temp["avatarUrl"]
            var comment: Comment?
            comment.commentLabel = commentDictionary["body"]
         comments.append(comment)
     }
```

This should be it.

Comment: A `struct` would really serve this purpose better than a `class`.